# Error in "from kapre.time_frequency import Melspectrogram, Spectrogram"

Tags: python

Error in importing  Melspectrogram,

```
"cannot import name 'Melspectrogram' from 'kapre.time_frequency' (C:\Users\Mr. SHADAB ALAM\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kapre\time_frequency.py)".
```

Although I have Kapre installed.

Answer (score 1):

It seams that since version 3.0, Melspectrogram class was removed and a mel spectrogram function was implemented in [composed.py:138](https://github.com/keunwoochoi/kapre/blob/f41eb4b2ba2fd484500584169ec05ae5e12e09b7/kapre/composed.py#L138)